# Match and mark the positions of elements of a vector along a given axis of a numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy

I want to mark all maxima along a given axis of an array (which shape may be n-dimensional), this works fine along the first one, but for the rest I can't figure it out. I don't want to iterate over axis, because there can be arbritarily many of them.

```
>>> A = range(5)*3
>>> A = array(a).reshape([3,5], order='F')
>>> A
array([[0, 3, 1, 4, 2],
       [1, 4, 2, 0, 3],
       [2, 0, 3, 1, 4]])
>>> B = amax(A, axis= 0)
>>> C = amax(A, axis= 1)
>>> B == A
array([[False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

This is what I want it to do for:

```
>>> C == A
False
```

but (of course) it does not.

How to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came up with:

```
def tiletuple(t,axis):
  m = [1]*t.ndim
  m[axis] = t.shape[axis]
  return m

ax = 1
tile(expand_dims(amax(A, axis=ax), axis=ax), tiletuple(A, ax)) == A
```

Answer (score 1):

In response to your direct example, when you do :

```
>>>A == C
False
```

it "doesn't work" because numpy doesn't understand how to broadcast the operation to give you the output your want.
using transpose twice you can get a simpler solution than what you proposed :

```
>>>C = amax(A, axis=1)
>>>transpose(C == transpose(A))
array([[False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: I just get 'False' back anyway.

Comment: Yes my bad I didn't get what you wanted correctly.
My solution works now and it is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but how about this one:

```
rollaxis(amax(A, ax)[...,newaxis], -1, ax) == A
```

It is basically inserting the axis again, which fell out of the array due to the amax. Then, the broadcasting works again.
Or, equivalently:

```
a = list(A.shape)
a[ax] = 1
amax(A, ax).reshape(a) == A
```